# Choose an item from JTable and put them on another

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add a CheckBox in JTable and when the user selects a question it will be added on another JTable but the priority is that I want to add the check box knowing that the JTable contains information taken from the database.
Thanks  for help . I hope that you understand me.
I made models I that's what I want to have [this is the models that i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN5A4.jpg)
This is the result of my code [The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNOgY.png)

```
 List<Question> questions=new ArrayList<>();
 JButton btnAfficher = new JButton("Afficher toutes les questions");
    btnAfficher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            categorie=GestionCategorieDelegate.doFindCategorieById(PreparerTest.idCategorie);
            questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareManuallyTest(categorie);
            initDataBindings();

        }
    });
    table_1 = new JTable();
    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(table_1);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    setLayout(groupLayout);
    initDataBindings();
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: *"..knowing that the JTable contains information taken from the database."* How is it relevant where the data comes from? Do you mean that when a table row is moved from one table to the other, it should be **deleted** from the DB?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson it's a simple code and Priyamal understood it i don't why you are not

Comment: @Andrew Thompson yeah that's it but i want the CheckBox firstly

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomTableModel mymodel = new CustomTableModel();
mymodel.addRow(new Object[]{false, "2ndcoldata", "3rdcol data"});
mymodel.addRow(new Object[]{true, "2ndcoldata", "3rdcol data"});
mytable.setModel(mymodel);


public class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    public MyTableModel() {
      super(new String[]{"col1", "col2", "col3"}, 0);

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
  Class clazz = String.class;
  switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
      clazz = Boolean.class;
      break;
  }
  return clazz;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
  return column == 0;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
  if (aValue instanceof Boolean && column == 0) {
    Vector rowData = (Vector)getDataVector().get(row);
    rowData.set(0, (boolean)aValue);
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
  }
}}
```

you can do it with above approach, i have customtableModel class which extends the DefaultTableModel class. and whenever you need to add data to the your table create an instance of CustomTableModel and add your row data to the model once it is completed then set the model to your jtable.

Comment: Thank you for you help but please where i put this code?

Comment: public TableCheckBox() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Select", "Contenu", "Reponses", "Niveau de difficulté"};
        Object[][] data = {
           what i put there to take the data from the data base
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model) 
        table = new JTable(model) {

Comment: Customnodel is a class so obviously you cant put it inside a method . And creating an instance of custommodel and adding data to that can be done inside a method

Comment: Sorry but can you explain more? how can i create an instance of customodel?

Comment: `CustomTableModel mymodel = new CustomTableModel();`

Comment: and then howa can i take DATA from the DataBASE (this the method how permet to me to take question from the DataBase 
questions=GestionTestDelegate.doPrepareManuallyTest(categorie);  )

Comment: I'm using bindings

Comment: DefaultTableModel required  super.setValueXxx instead of fireTableCellUpdated (already implemented and correctly)